# How many phone numbers i can associate with one messaging service in twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

i am using twilio messaging service in my webapp. Here, each phone number have its own messaging service. I want to associate all phone numbers to 1 messaging service. Is it possible to send and receive messages on each phone number using 1 messaging service?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

According to [this article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402434663195-How-many-Twilio-numbers-or-senders-can-I-have-in-a-Messaging-Service-):

> A Twilio Messaging Service can contain up to 400 Twilio message senders by default, including phone numbers, short codes, Alpha Sender ID, and WhatsApp senders.

And if you need more, you can contact support.

Comment: How can i send and receive message on each phone number using this messaging service?

Comment: You can send an SMS message with a number by using it directly in the `from` parameter when [calling the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?#create-a-call-resource). Or, you can pass the messaging service Sid instead and the messaging service will choose which number to use to send the message. When replying to incoming messages, you set a webhook URL in the messaging service and respond with TwiML and the number that received the incoming message will make the response. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, got it. Thanku @philnash

Comment: Recently, you can tell the messaging service to use the webook assigned to the individual number as well, which may best fit your needs, https://www.twilio.com/changelog/messaging-services-defer-to-senders-webhook-option-now-available

Comment: Ah, TIL! Thanks @Alan